# Is there a way to export all categories into a csv?

Tags: magento-1, csv, importexport, export

Is there a way to export all categories into a csv?

Im moving data from a non-magento store into a fresh build.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could write this one pretty easily.  Create a PHP file called something like `export.php`.

```
<?php

require("app/Mage.php");  // load the main Mage file
Mage::app();   // not run() because you just want to load Magento, not run it.

// load all of the active categories in the system and include all attributes
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
              ->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addIsActiveFilter();

 $export_file = "var/export/categories.csv"; // assumes that you're running from the web root. var/ is typically writable
 $export = fopen($export_file, 'w') or die("Permissions error."); // open the file for writing.  if you see the error then check the folder permissions.

 $output = "";

 $output = "id,name\r\n"; // column names. end with a newline.
 fwrite($export, $output); // write the file header with the column names


 foreach ($categories as $category) {
     $output = ""; // re-initialize $output on each iteration
     $output .= $category->getId().','; // no quote - integer
     $output .= '"'.$category->getName().'",'; // quotes - string
     // add any other fields you want here 
     $output .= "\r\n"; // add end of line
     fwrite($export, $output); // write to the file handle "$export" with the string "$output".
 }

 fclose($export); // close the file handle.
```

You could write an import in a similar way, but use `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')` with magic sets to fill in the fields to create new categories while parsing the file you've created.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to use addslashes (http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) around my category names.

Comment: how can i import, need help..

Comment: @matinict : You can use magmi, its best for products import

Comment: @ seanbreeden : Like this way any script for export all products

Comment: how can i export sku and category path, not category name

Comment: You wouldn't be able to export SKU using this routine. Do you mean the products contained in the category?

Comment: perfect !!! with explanations +1

Answer (score 2):

Wasn't keen on @seanbreeden answer because it wont work properly if your exporting the category description and they have HTML or returns in any of the categories' fields like description etc.

Here's my solution (which you visit in the browser and it downloads it):

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.csv');

// Load the Magento core
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);

// Load the category collection
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addIsActiveFilter();

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
// can change this so it downloads it to a file on the server
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('id', 'name', 'description', 'title', 'meta_description'));

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $id = $category->getId();
    $name = $category->getName();
    $description = $category->getDescription();
    $title = $category->getMetaTitle();
    $metaD = $category->getMetaDescription();

    fputcsv($output, array($id, $name, $description, $title, $metaD));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Varien_File_Csv::saveData($file, $data)`. I guess its easier then using `fopen`, `fwrite`, ... directly. Also you dont have to take care of permissions, when creating a new export directory. To add fields, you just have to just change `$columns` variable.

This will save your CSV to `var/export/...`

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

/** @var array $columns matches atttribute code*/
$columns = array(
    'entity_id',
    'path',
    'name',
    'description',
);

$data = array(
    $columns,
);

$categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect($columns);
    //->addIsActiveFilter();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $row = array();
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        $row[] = $category->getData($column);
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}

$path = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'export' . DS . 'your_directory';
$file = 'categories.csv';

// create directory under var/export
$io = new Varien_Io_File();
$io->checkAndCreateFolder($path);

$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csv->setEnclosure('|'); # change enclosure to work with html
$csv->saveData($path . DS. $file, $data);
```

Out ...

```
|entity_id|,|path|,|name|,|description|
|1|,|1|,|Root Catalog|,||
|2|,|1/2|,|Default Category|,||
|4|,|1/2/4|,|Dogs|,|<span class="empty"><span>|
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt,In magento you can find of lot of extesion  which are  export /import category in csv.Using this you can fill your requirement

In my point of view   best in free extension in this purpose if:

[Magentoworks.net](http://www.magentoworks.net/importexport-magento-category-extension/)

**PaiD:**

[MagentoCommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-category-import-export.html)

[commerceextensions](http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-bulk-categories-import-export-csv-xml.html)

More extension in MagentoConnection [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=category%20export%2Fimport&pl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Even though you accepted an answer , I think the easiet method is to export all products to CSV and then use excel to distinct the categories field.

Using code or extension if its for a once in a while export , is waste of time and is another class you need to support in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. You can use a third-party tool called [Skyvia](https://skyvia.com/connectors/magento) for this purpose. It connects to Magento via its API and allows exporting all major Magento tables in CSV files. It has a free account, too, so you can test it. Saves a lot of time as requires little to no configuration and coding

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be to go to:

Magento2 > Catalog > Categories...

... then click on 'Expand All' and copy and paste the full list of categories into a word or excel document.

This was the quickest way of getting a list of all existing categories for me... some further formatting in excel or word was required, but it did the job.

Answer (score -1):

First let me apologize for not having a fancy code to show off programming skills I dont have.

This is how i did it, simply made a product called "0000allcatagories" and just made that product (via lots of clicks) a member of all my catagories.  A simple export to a CSV and viola, a list of all the catagories..... now if only i can figure out how to do the same with attributes B)

i found a program called "catagory upload for magento" ... which does a very nice job of downloading catagories... and if you can edit a spreadsheet you can upload catagories as well.... very nice.

good luck