# How to export orders in csv file?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, sales-order, export

I'm new on Magento.

How to export orders with code SKU price etc.

I read the link below but didn't get where to add this code and how this code works please help.

> [Programmatically Export Sales order customer details to excel format](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132752/programmatically-export-sales-order-customer-details-to-excel-format/209509#209509)

Comment: Create orderExport.php on magento root directory and add this code and run the file in browser.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it is helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    require_once("app/Mage.php");
    Mage::app();
    Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $orders->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
    $fp = fopen('export.csv', 'w');

    $header = array("Customer ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "City",  "Telephone", "Country", "Postcode", "Status");
    fputcsv($fp, $header);

    foreach($orders as $order) {
        $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $countryCode = $billingAddress->getCountryId();
        $country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->loadByCode($countryCode);
        $countryName = $country->getName();

        $fields = array($order->getId(), $billingAddress->getFirstname(),$billingAddress->getLastname(), $billingAddress->getEmail(), $billingAddress->getCity(),  $billingAddress->getTelephone(), $countryName, $billingAddress->getPostcode(), $order->getStatus());
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
?>
```

Please try this, Its working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script to export order

```
<?php    
require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app();

    $data=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

    $fp = fopen('exports_order.csv', 'w+');
    $csvHeader = array('ID','STATUS');
    fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        fputcsv($fp, array($row->getId(),$row->getStatus()), ",");
    }
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: where should i use this script

Comment: create test.php file in root

Comment: i didn't see any other information accept get mail or order i want complete order detail like sku price inventory

Comment: i have file orderExport.php with the above code

Comment: you change code as per your requirment , current code genrate exports_order.csv file in your root with order id and order status only

Comment: what about the csv file created by magneto in default is it the same or change?

Comment: magneto only export product and customer

Comment: what about this code http://www.mrmagento.com/wp-content/uploads/unproccessed-orders.zip

Comment: my code is working for me

Comment: I'm sure this works, but I'd prefer `Varien_File_Csv` over `fputcsv()` .... see https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212078/46249